# How to permanently use straight instead of smart quotes in Microsoft Office for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

Every time I change the settings in Microsoft office to use straight instead of smart quotes, it will reset itself back to smart quotes after a few days or weeks. I'm not sure what the trigger is to reset itself; restarting Microsoft Office doesn't seem to do it. I rarely restart the computer, perhaps that is it, or something else.

I use the following steps to turn off smart quotes:

1. Go to File>Options>Mail>Spelling and Autocorrect>Autocorrect Options
2. In the `AutoFormat as you Type` tab, I uncheck `"Straight quotes" with "smart quotes"`.
3. In the `AutoFormat` tab, I uncheck `"Straight quotes" with "smart quotes"`.

How do I prevent Microsoft office from resetting these settings?

Comment: MS Word, Excel etc. have templates that can be personalized, not sure about  Outlook. See https://www.pcworld.com/article/3269282/microsoft-word-templates-how-to-use-modify-and-create-them.html